# PySide, editing spinbox colors

Tags: pyside2

How in PySide would you edit the background color of the field of a spinbox, using stylesheets, but not change the color of the up-button and the down-buttons? Is there a flag to only adjust the "field?"

```
self.intensity_multiplier_spinbox_list[iter].setStyleSheet("QDoubleSpinBox {background-color: orange;color: black};")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QPalette`:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox()
    pal = w.palette()
    pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QColor("orange"))
    w.setPalette(pal)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]